# SharePoint Online Site Collection PropertyBag - how to apply crawled property to child content of site collection (e.g. documents in library)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, crawled-property, refinement-panel, property-bag

In my enterprise search page, I want users to be able to filter their results by choosing 'site' metadata. I've already setup a filter for site name using the ows_SiteName crawled property - it works great and it applies to the content of the site in search! But I have other metadata about each site that I want users to filter on - let's use 'Client' as an example. I've setup this other metadata as properties in the Site Collection PropertyBag and marked them as indexable. This works! I mapped the crawled property to a managed property, and setup my filter to include this property. This works to an extent but the property only seems to filter results from search which are 'sites'. I want the filter to also apply to the content of my site (e.g. documents in a library).

Comment: As a workaround, I've added this metadata as site columns and put them onto the content types that I care about with default values. It's not ideal but it works.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for this as well. I can search by site property bag, but it only returns "site" type items, doenst return any contained items ( documents in te site for instance )